# how to determine the shape of .tsv file through python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, size, shapes

I have a .tsv file that looks like this [.tsv File structure in MSExcel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkEc1.png)

I want to determine its shape through pytorch. How Can I do that

I wrote a code

> import pandas as pd
>
> df = pd.read_csv(path/to/.tsv)
>
> df.shape

and it output

> (13596, 1)

But clearly the shape conflicts the image that I provided. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify how the data is delimited when using pd.read_csv (unless it is comma separated)

`df = pd.read_csv(path/to/.tsv, sep = '\t')`

Should load the data correctly.

See: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Edit: looking at your data you should also specify `header=None` because you don't have a header row. Ideally also supply a list of column names using the `names` parameter of `pd.read_csv`

Comment: It gave me following error 


ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 6 fields in line 10553, saw 11

Comment: your data has some rows with either bad data or some fields contain tabs.

error_bad_lines=False will ignore these records

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are missing seperator attribute

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data/test.txt")
print(df.shape)
```

**Output: (2, 1)**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data/test.txt", sep='\t')
print(df.shape)
```

**Output: (2, 3)**

So please add `sep='\t'` to your read_csv

Also If you have a header, you can pass header=0

```
pd.read_csv("data/test.txt", sep='\t', header=0)
```

Plz let me know if it helps

Comment: yes using "sep='\t'" along with adding "error_bad_lines=False" worked